# How to know what to import into the Python Interpreter in order to use installed python library

Tags: python, pip, installation

I have installed a python library called PyRadiomics by doing:
 `pip install pyradiomics`

When I do `pip freeze | grep pyra` in the command prompt, I see `pyradiomics==2.0.0` clearly showing that the library was installed.

When I start a python interpreter and do `import pyradiomics`, it does not work. I realized that I need to do `import radiomics`.

I just happened to figure this out by luck. 
How is someone supposed to know how to import a library into their python script after installing it using pip. It seems that currently, you could install a library with `pip install some_name` and have to do `import some_other_name` in your Python code. I have been using Python for a while but never came across this before which lead me to assume that `some_name` is always the same as `some_other_name` but I found out that this is not the case. 
How is someone supposed to know what that other name is after installing a library called `some_name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pip` can list installed files for any package installed by it:

```
$ pip show -f packagename
```

Doing some simple output filtering/transforming with bash, you can easily come up with a custom command that will list all Python packages/modules in a package, for example:

```
$ pip show -f packagename | grep "\.py$" | sed 's/\.py//g; s,/__init__,,g; s,/,.,g'
```

Example output with the `wheel` package:

```
$ pip install wheel
...
$ pip show -f wheel | grep "\.py$" | sed 's/\.py//g; s,/__init__,,g; s,/,.,g'
 wheel
 wheel.__main__
 wheel.archive
 wheel.bdist_wheel
 wheel.egg2wheel
 wheel.install
 wheel.metadata
 wheel.paths
 wheel.pep425tags
 wheel.pkginfo
 wheel.signatures
 wheel.signatures.djbec
 wheel.signatures.ed2551
 wheel.signatures.keys
 wheel.tool
 wheel.util
 wheel.wininst2wheel
```

You can even alias it to a custom shell command, for example `pip-list-modules`. In your `~/.bashrc` (Linux) / `~/.bash_profile` (MacOS):

```bash
function pip-list-modules() {
    pip show -f "$@" | grep "\.py$" | sed 's/\.py//g; s,/__init__,,g; s,/,.,g'
}
```

Test it:

```bash
$ pip-list-modules setuptools wheel pip  # multiple packages can passed at once
```

Comment: This is very handy. I think there is a bug in the regular expression that makes `sed` trim a leading `py` from the name of the package. Try `pip-list-modules pygments` to see what I mean.

Comment: @NickChammas you're right, missed a backslash before the dot, turning it into a glob. Thank you for the hint!